# Adding firebase analytics into tvos and macos project

Tags: macos, firebase, tvos, firebase-analytics

Is there a way to add firebase analytics events into my tvos project and macos project? I found tutorials to add it only into ios app.

Comment: Firebase does not officially support macOS or tvOS at this time - they dropped support after v2 (ugh). However, there is an open source project that you should look into [Firebase iOS Open Source Development](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#community-supported-efforts)

Comment: There is no firebase analytics functional...

Comment: Correct according to that site. Hopefully someone will contribute something along those lines in the future on that site.

Answer (score 0):

As of the 8.9.0 release, Firebase has official beta support for tvOS and macOS.